# Debugging Playframework Anorm with Oracle

Tags: oracle, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I just tried to switch a playframework 2.1 scala project from a h2 database to oracle via jdbc. The connection seems to work, but now I get this very generic error (see below).

It essentially is:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Now, I do not get any indication about where this has happened and where I have to look for the problem.

Any ideas about how I can get more decent information about the problem, like where in the application it occurs?

---

> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected
>   exception[SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found
>   where expected ]
>           at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
>           at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
>           at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
>           at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
>           at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) [scala-library.jar:na] Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]

Comment: Try turning on logging: `db.default.logStatements=true`, to see what SQLs are actually being executed.

Comment: Ok, I added that string to my application.conf but currently i still do not see the queries in logs/application.log?